# Intelligent Management of Large Session Values

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session

I have an application containing a 'wizard' like workflow, wherein users edit a large collection of objects and once complete they can choose to save or cancel their edits. Given the size of the objects, storing them client side and round tripping them is not feasible. Instead we use session state to store the objects, and use ajax methods to retrieve/edit them.

My problem is that, if the user chooses to navigate away from the current page without completing this workflow, then the object collection stays in the session until the session expires or the user begins the same workflow over again. Given that there may be many concurrent users and that the object collection can get fairly large (i.e. >2MB per user) I'm concerned that this will cause needless memory consumption and potential performance degradation.

Certainly there are other approaches available that do not use session (i.e. writing to temp tables), however, I was wondering if there is a way to intelligently detect when a user navigates away from a controller so that I may perform some sort of cleanup (delete the unnecessary session variables).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Detecting when a user leaves a page is tough.  While there are a few options out there, the most reliable is probably polling, which isn't perfect.  For example, if a user's connection flakes out for a few seconds, then you could wipe out their session.

You also can't just wipe out the wizard session objects if any page on the app outside of the wizard has activity by the user.  This solution fails if a user opens multiple tabs/windows.

If it's possible to put a timer on your wizard, then I'd set a manager in state to manage wizard object collections by user.  That manager would have the last activity date for every object, and you'd set up a sliding expiration to wipe out any session objects which haven't had activity in X minutes.

This solution would allow you to edit the length of your wizard timer to balance user needs with server resources.  If your session is consuming too much memory, then reduce the sliding expiration, or vice versa.